# How to ensure multiple jms listener instances process messages only when currently executing listener instance acknowlege

Tags: spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms, jmstemplate

I'm currently trying to build a messaging application using JMS Listener and IBM MQ, and I need to ensure that I can run two instances of the same listener at the same time. However, I want to make sure that the second instance waits until the first instance has fully processed and acknowledged the message.
I'm using Spring Boot for my application, JMS Listener and IBM MQ.

Below is the my config class which is annotated with @component and @EnableJMS

```java
    public class jmsconfig{

     @Bean
     public MQConnectionfactory getConnectionFactory(){
         MQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new MQConnectionFactory();
         connectionFactory.setQueueManagerName("AA");
         connectionFactory.setExpirationTimeOut(3600000);
         connectionFactory.setPerformExpiration(true);
         connectionFactory.setPerformValidation(true);
         connectionFactory.setPerformOptimalSizeCheck(false);
         connectionFactory.setValidationTimeOut(180000);
         connectionFactory.setMinIdle(3);
         connectionFactory.setMaxIdle(5);
         reurn connectionFactory ;
    }
    
     @Bean(name="jmsListenerContainerFactory")
     public JmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(MQConnectionfactory mqConnectionfactory){
         DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory  containerFactory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
         containerFactory.setConnectionFactor(mqConnectionfactory);
         containerFactory.setSessionTransacted(true);
         containerFactory.setSessionAcknowledgementMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDE)
         reurn containerFactory ;
    }
    
}
```

Listener code:

```java
     @Component
        public class Receiver {
          
          public sttaic int count = 0;
        
          @JmsListener(destination = "${inwardQueueName}", containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
          public void receiveMessage(javax.jms.Message message) throws javax.jms.JMSException {
            String messagetxt = "";
            OrderObject order = null;
            if (message instanceof javax.jms.TextMessage) {
              messagetxt = ((TextMessage)message).getText();
              OrderObject order = //code to covert messagetxt to object
              System.out.println("Message pciked up with Order Id : " +order.getOrderId)
              TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(15);
              count++;
             if(order.getOrderId==1){
              if(count<=4){
                throw new Exception("Exception occurred");
              }
            }
            }
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(15);
            System.out.println("Message Acknowledged for orderId: " +order.getOrderId)
            message.acknowledge();
          }
        }
```

I start the first instance and pushes first message to MQ with orderId 1. It prints the below statement and then waits for 15 seconds

```
Message picked up with Order Id : 1
```

Immediately, I start the second instance and then pushes second message to MQ with orderId 2. I can see the below output on the console.

```
Message picked up withorderId 2
Message Acknowledged for orderId: 2
```

After some time, when the first instance completes(since there is a wait of 15 sec), I can see the below output.

```
Message pciked up with Order Id : 1
Message pciked up with Order Id : 1
Message pciked up with Order Id : 1
Message Acknowledged for orderId: 1
```

With the above output, the Second instance is picking up second message from the MQ in parallel and process them while the first instance is still processing the first message.

**Can anyone help with what is wrong with the above implementation?**

Comment: MQ is designed for parallel processing. What you describe sounds exactly as expected. What do you think you have done to avoid the parallel processing that one would expect?

Comment: It shows message with order id 1 picked 3 times... is this because there are 3 messages each with order id 1 ? Or is there a typo?

Comment: @colinpaice  for order id 1 , we throwing exception which leads the same message to be redelivered. This is expected.

Comment: @MoragHughson  totally agree with you. But my use case is to implement sequential execution. Above mq configuration indicates , execution should take place sequentially but somehow it is not working.

Comment: So I would ask again - what is it that you think you have configured differently to try to avoid the parallel processing?

Comment: Transacted sessions need to be finalized by a session commit and acknowledge mode is ignored.  Non transacted sessions with acknowledge mode set to client acknowledge need message.acknowledge().  You can't have both.   This still doesn't explain why you think the only one listener can pick up at a time.   Maybe you could set the queue for exclusive and then only one listener could be connected at a time but that may not be what you want.

Comment: @MoragHughson, see in config file containerFactory.setSessionTransacted(true);
         containerFactory.setSessionAcknowledgementMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDE) and in listener class message.acknowledge().

Comment: See my comment,  things don't work the way you think they do.   Acknowledge is ignored on a transacted session.

Comment: @JoshMc I agree with you. But when I remove containerFactory.setSessionTransacted(true);   seems the listener is not able to pick a message from mq. Am I missing something here? Can you point me to some reference link? That would be of great help.

Comment: It should be false if your want to use client acknowledge

Comment: @JoshMc I did test with false but still listener working in parallel mode.

Comment: That is how listeners work.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description it looks like message 2 shouldn't be processed until the actions needed for message 1 have completed, once they have then it doesn't matter which listener works on message 2. Sequencing is key and not which listener does the processing.

To do this, message 2 needs to be tied into message 1.

One way would be for the producer app not to place message 2 on the queue until the processing for message 1 has been approved.

Another way would be to tie message 2 with message 1 (maybe via specific queues or via properties, or via priority, or a permutation of these) such that they are always read as a pair and as part of a transaction.

IE.

- Start Transaction
- Ensure both messages are read together, making sure that some other process, or listener can't or doesn't see message 2. Only the `@JMSListener` that receives message 1 would know how to obtain message 2, which it does using normal JMS Get logic.
- Process message 1
- Process message 2
- Commit, so both messages can be removed.

You could commit between message 1 & 2, but if there is a failure, how do you detect that message 1 was processed so you can process message 2. Logic to start processing from message 2 gets very complicated if you commit here.